# What is the xpath for retrieving all attribute nodes (whatever be the attributes name) with a specified value?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Following is a sample xml.

```
<library>
    <book id="aaa">
      <title id="bbb">Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince</title>
      <author id="ccc" ref="zzz"/>
    </book>
    <book id="ddd">
      <title id="eee">Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone</title>
      <author id="fff" ref="zzz"/>
    </book>
    <author-details id="zzz">
      <firstName id="ggg">Joanne</firstName>
      <lastName id="hhh"/>Rowling</lastName>
    </author-details>
</library>
```

There are many more books in this example and many author details as well.
What I want, is **to retrieve all attribute nodes, what ever be the attributes name, with a specified value.**
For example, in the above sample I want the xpath to return the following nodes.
(all attribute nodes that contain the value of 'zzz', what ever be the attributes name).

1. ref="zzz" from the first book node.
2. ref="zzz" from the second book node.
3. and, id="zzz" from author-details node.

I am writing Java code and want to change the value of the id='zzz' to some other value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `//@*` gives you all attribute nodes, add a predicate `//@*[. = 'zzz']` and you have all attribute nodes with the value `zzz`.